# How could a macro return an aligned pointer to an unaligned value?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99

I have been looking into an existing C99 code base that uses pointers to packed structure members all over the place. This results in warnings of the form.

```
my_file.c:xxx:yy: error: taking address of packed member of 'struct some_packed_struct' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Werror=address-of-packed-member]
```

Most of the time, those warnings are generated when passing a pointer to a member of a structure to a function. For example:

```c
int bar(const int *val)
{ ... }

struct {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
} __attribute__((packed)) foo;

// &foo.c is not aligned
bar(&foo.c)
```

There are a lot of different solutions to this problem. One that immediately comes to mind is to `memcpy()` the value to a stack-allocated variable of the same type and pass a pointer to this stack variable.

```c
int tmp;

memcpy(&tmp, &foo.c, sizeof(foo.c));
bar(&tmp)
```

While this works, it will result in a lot of boiler-plate code which I would rather avoid introducing.

For now, I have been contemplating using a macro of the form

```
#define ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(val) (&((const typeof(val)) { val }))

bar(ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(foo.c));
```

This works well for scalar types. However, and predictably, if `val` is a `struct`, this will not work.

```c
struct inner {
    int c, d;
};

struct outer {
    int a, b;
    struct inner inner;
};

void print_inner_field(const struct inner *inner)
{
    printf("value is %d\n", inner->c);
}

struct outer outer;

print_inner_field(ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(outer.inner));
```

```
lol.c:28:30: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘struct inner’
   28 |  print_inner(ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(foo.inner));
      |                              ^~~
lol.c:3:55: note: in definition of macro ‘ALIGN_VALUE_PTR’
    3 | #define ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(val) (&((const typeof(val)) { val }))
      |                                                       ^~~
```

I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea than what I have come up with.

Comment: What would happen if you just dropped the `__attribute__((packed))`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle in this specific case, lots of network protocol breakage as those structures are directly sent/received through sockets.

Comment: A better idea would be dropping the convention of passing pointers and pass values instead, since if this works there's no point in passing by reference.

Comment: I think there's some XY problem going on here too, but the question of "how you make a compound literal temp-copy of a struct" is interesting and useful outside the context of packed structures (which are evil).

Comment: Agreed about passing by value, that would have been an interesting alternative. However, some of the call sites are external libraries (OSS) which would be impractical to change for that reason alone.

Comment: Regarding the XY problem, you are correct. I am not condoning the use of packed structures, but in trying to find a quick fix, I was confronted with this compound literal question which I thought was an interesting brain teaser.

Comment: Your first paragraph ends "warnings of the form" and doesn't show the form of the warnings.  Please either rephrase the sentence so the omission doesn't matter, or (probably better), please show one or more of the warnings you get.

Comment: With your '`memcpy` to `tmp`' variant, you're passing the variable by reference to the function, so presumably the function might modify it, and therefore presumably you should also `memcpy` from `tmp` back into the unaligned structure.  Or you should ask yourself "why is the function passed a pointer?" (even if it is a pointer to const data).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah that was my thought too, but the `const` helps avoid the problem as long as the code is const-correct.

Comment: I was returning a `const` pointer in my original macro to prevent (or at least discourage) the use of this macro when the pointer argument of the callee is used as an output parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define ALIGN_VALUE_PTR(val) (((const typeof(val) []) { val }))
```

The reason your original version does not work is because of subtleties how braces are treated in initializers, and the fact that compound literals always require at least one level of braces. You can initialize a struct as

```
struct s bar;
//...
struct s foo = bar;
```

but you can't do:

```
struct s foo = { bar };
```

because, inside the braces, `bar` would have to have type matching the first member of `struct s`, not `struct s`.

Using an array (or a structure; there are variants involving a gratuitous structure too) allows you to match the brace levels to use the struct type you wanted as the initializer. The array form of course starts out with array type and only becomes a pointer via decay. If you want to ensure it's always a pointer, add a gratuitous `+0` or `&*` to force the decay.